# Google Contacts API v3 OAuth2 does not allow administrator to retrieve contacts of another user, is there any other way to do this?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-apps, google-contacts-api

Google Contacts API v3 OAuth2 does not allow the administrator to retrieve the contacts of another user.  We are not willing to use OAuth 1.0 as it is deprecated.  The access token generation for service account will affect our product's performance.
Is there any other way of getting the contacts of another user?  Why should the super administrator of a domain not be allowed to read these?

Answer (score 0):

OAuth 2.0 Service Accounts are the proper way to do domain-wide delegation. If you are caching the access token for it's full lifetime the performance impact should be minimal. Can you offer more details about why performance is unacceptable?

Comment: Pardon me if I am wrong but isn't the lifetime of an access token just one hour, referred this link - https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount 
We are currently using OAuth2.0 (admin access) where we retrieve an access token before firing any transaction.  
If a service account is used, we will have to form the JWT, sign it and request for a new access token each time, right?

Comment: No, you'll have the access token available for the full hour... Cache the token for the time it is valid, that will reduce the round trip time.

Comment: Could you please tell me if service accounts are supported for the following scopes -
1. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group
2. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit
3. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user
4. https://www.google.com/m8/feeds
5. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.groups.settings
6. https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/